# The application may be doing too much work on its main thread (navigation drawer)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, navigation-drawer, slowdown

I am new to java and I got an error that couldn't fix.
My app is using the navigation drawer and when I open it the app gets really slow and the logcat displays the message of frame skipping and The application may be doing too much work on its main thread...

Don't know what to do to fix it.
This is part of the code where the drawer is called.

```
public class MainActivity extends SwipeRefreshActivity implements
    LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private View mPanelMenu;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
// nav drawer title
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
// used to store app title
private CharSequence mTitle;
private Menu[] MENUS;
public static Location location;
public static List<Address> address;
public static int offsetY = 0;

private static SQLiteDatabase db;
private static DbHelper dbHelper;
private static Queries q;
protected static ImageLoader imageLoader;
private static boolean isShownSplash = false;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;

// Handle to SharedPreferences for this app
SharedPreferences mPrefs;

// Handle to a SharedPreferences editor
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
private Fragment currFragment;

private GetAddressTask getAddressTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
    this.getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.header_logo);
    this.getActionBar().setTitle("");

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    q = new Queries(db, dbHelper);

    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration
            .createDefault(getBaseContext()));

    statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
    mTwitter = new TwitterApp(this, twitterAppListener);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = "";
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
    mPanelMenu = findViewById(R.id.panel_slidermenu);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
    mDrawerList.setDividerHeight(0);

    updateMenuList();

    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_menu, // nav
                                // menu
                                // toggle
                                // icon
            R.string.no_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                // accessibility
            R.string.no_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                // accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
        offsetY = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }

    if (!isShownSplash) {
        isShownSplash = true;
        this.getActionBar().hide();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, new SplashFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    else if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(1);
    }

    mUpdatesRequested = false;

    // Open Shared Preferences
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(LocationUtils.SHARED_PREFERENCES,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Get an editor
    mEditor = mPrefs.edit();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

    FrameLayout frameAds = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameAds);
    frameAds.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if (MGUtilities.hasConnection(this)) {
        q.deleteTable("stores");
        q.deleteTable("categories");
        q.deleteTable("photos");
        q.deleteTable("reviews");
        q.deleteTable("ratings");
        q.deleteTable("news");
    }
}

public void showMainView() {
    getActionBar().show();
    displayView(1);
    showAds();
}

private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        updateMenuList();
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // case R.id.action_settings:
    // return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu) {
    // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
    // boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
    // menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void displayView(int position) {

    // clear back stack
    FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    for (int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
        fm.popBackStackImmediate(null,
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {

    case 1:
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new CategoryFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new FavoriteFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        fragment = new FeaturedFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new MapFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new SearchFragment();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new NewsFragment();
        break;
    case 8:
        fragment = new WeatherFragment();
        break;

    case 10:
        fragment = new AboutUsFragment();
        break;
    case 11:
        fragment = new TermsConditionFragment();
        break;

    case 13:

        UserAccessSession session = UserAccessSession.getInstance(this);
        if (session.getUserSession() == null) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        break;

    case 14:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(i);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
    // setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mPanelMenu);

    if (currFragment != null && fragment != null) {
        boolean result = fragment.getClass()
                .equals(currFragment.getClass());
        if (result)
            return;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {

        if (fragment instanceof MapFragment) {
            currFragment = fragment;
            Handler h = new Handler();
            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.this
                            .getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.frame_container, currFragment)
                            .commit();
                }
            }, Config.DELAY_SHOW_ANIMATION + 200);
        } else {

            currFragment = fragment;
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = this
                    .getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}

public void updateMenuList() {

    UserAccessSession accessSession = UserAccessSession.getInstance(this);
    UserSession userSession = accessSession.getUserSession();

    if (userSession == null) {
        MENUS = UIConfig.MENUS_NOT_LOGGED;
    } else {
        MENUS = UIConfig.MENUS_LOGGED;
    }

    showList();
}

public void showList() {

    MGListAdapter adapter = new MGListAdapter(this, MENUS.length,
            R.layout.menu_entry);

    adapter.setOnMGListAdapterAdapterListener(new OnMGListAdapterAdapterListener() {

        @Override
        public void OnMGListAdapterAdapterCreated(MGListAdapter adapter,
                View v, int position, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            FrameLayout frameCategory = (FrameLayout) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.frameCategory);
            View frameHeader = v.findViewById(R.id.frameHeader);

            frameCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            frameHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            Menu menu = MENUS[position];

            if (menu.getHeaderType() == HeaderType.HeaderType_CATEGORY) {
                frameCategory.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Spanned title = Html.fromHtml(MainActivity.this
                        .getResources().getString(menu.getMenuResTitle()));
                TextView tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
                tvTitle.setText(title);

                ImageView imgViewIcon = (ImageView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgViewIcon);
                imgViewIcon.setImageResource(menu.getMenuResIconSelected());
            } else {
                frameHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Spanned title = Html.fromHtml(MainActivity.this
                        .getResources().getString(menu.getMenuResTitle()));
                TextView tvTitleHeader = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvTitleHeader);
                tvTitleHeader.setText(title);
            }
        }
    });
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Below is the adapter code

```
public class MGListAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

Context c;
private int count;
private int resId;
OnMGListAdapterAdapterListener mCallback;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private int mLastPosition = 1;

public interface OnMGListAdapterAdapterListener {

    public void OnMGListAdapterAdapterCreated(MGListAdapter 
            adapter, View v, int position, ViewGroup viewGroup);
}

public void setOnMGListAdapterAdapterListener(OnMGListAdapterAdapterListener listener) {

    try {
        mCallback = (OnMGListAdapterAdapterListener) listener;
    } catch (ClassCastException e)  {
        throw new ClassCastException(this.toString() + " must implement OnMGListAdapterAdapterListener");
    }
}


public MGListAdapter(Context c, int count, int resId) {
    this.c = c;
    this.count = count;
    this.resId = resId;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return count;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pos;
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View v, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = li.inflate(resId, null);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.view = v;
        v.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        Log.w("MGListAdapter Class", "View being reused.");
    }

    if(mCallback != null)
        mCallback.OnMGListAdapterAdapterCreated(this, viewHolder.view, pos, viewGroup);



    return v;
}

public class ViewHolder {

    public View view;
}
```

}

Comment: Hi, that is just a warning, the app did not crash yet at that point

Comment: Yes, it did not crash, but gets really slow when open, close or slide up/down the menu.

Comment: It's true for some devices. Navigation predefines its animations after all.. so lesser device spec more burden

Comment: The strange is that I am testing on Motorola Droid Maxx (2.7ghz quad) and android 5.0.2... it wasn't supposed to slowdown.

Comment: Can you share your adapter code? it looks like your adapter might be doing a lot of generating views.

Comment: Can you try to isolate the problem down to less code? It isn't very helpful to just dump the whole logic of the activity. If you can isolate the problem and recreate it with just the drawer opening, it will help us answer you better

Comment: @Gaurav - Hi, have added the adapter code, thanks.

Comment: @nmio - I will try it, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Ok guys, I found my error, it was a really stupid error on my side...
At the drawable folder I forgot to resize the menu's icons, it was at 500px, now that I have resized all the icons the Drawer Menu is normal again, no warning messages.

Thanks @Sheychan, @Gaurav and @nmio for the efforts.

Comment: Thank you ! Best answer for my problem :)